# How does %If %else work in SAS Macro

Tags: macros, sas, sas-macro

I have the following code:

```
%macro TEST();
%let prev=3;
%do i=1 %to 4;
    %if &i>2 %then %do;
        %put prev = 5;
    %end;
    %else; 
        %put prev = 0;
    %end;
%end;
%mend;
```

Which, when executed, returns:

```
prev = 0
prev = 0
prev = 5
prev = 0
prev = 5
prev = 0
```

My question is - how does the if-else statements work in SAS Macro - why is the else statment always executed?

Comment: Your code won't run on my machine, syntax error.   ERROR: There is no matching %DO statement for the %END. This statement will be ignored. See @vknowles solution for an answer.

Comment: The `%ELSE` is followed by and empty statement. The second `%PUT` is not part of the `%ELSE` clause so that is why it always runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't run for me, it generates an error.

> ERROR: There is no matching %DO statement for the %END. This statement will be ignored.

I believe you intended the following, which is close to the other solution but not quite. Rather than add a %do, move the %put statement.

```
%macro TEST();
    %let prev=3;

    %do i=1 %to 4;

        %if &i>2 %then
            %do;
                %put prev = 5;
            %end;
        %else
            %put prev = 0;
    %end;
%mend;

%test;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has an error in it. The `%ELSE` statement doesn't do anything because of a missing `%DO`. Therefore, the second `%PUT` statement is always executed.

It should read:

```
%macro TEST();
%let prev=3;
%do i=1 %to 4;
    %if &i>2 %then %do;
        %put prev = 5;
    %end;
    %else %do; /* <=== */
        %put prev = 0;
    %end;
%end;
%mend;
```